Flutter make queries in Firestore
Is there a way I can make queries in Firestore where the queries contain the value of TextEditing controller?
TextEditingController fromController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController toController = TextEditingController();

StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("collectionPath")
                      .where("DepartureCity", arrayContains: [
                      fromController.text.toLowerCase(),
                      ])
                      .where("ArrivalCity", arrayContains: 
                       [toController.text.toLowerCase()])
                      .snapshots(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot){
                          try{}on FirebaseException catch (e){}
                        },
                      );

The thing is I have two TextFields. one with fromController and the other with toController. I want the queries to return a list from the database with where as an argument. That is, if the fromController.text is found in the field DepartureCity, and also if the toController.text is found in the field ArrivalCity the list should be displayed.
I'm not really concerned but the list being displayed. I'm more concerned about the query aspect.
I tried the above code, but the error says I can use arrayContains ONLY ONCE.
In my case UserA makes a post that he is going from point A to point B, represented by "departureCity" and "arrivalCity" in the database, using google places. I even stored the GeoPoints in the database. So let's say the UserA puts the location "New York, Time Square" as the "departureCity", and UserB puts "New York, Statue of Liberty" as his "departureCity", then UserC wants to move from anywhere in New York. So when he types in "New York" using the fromController he should be able to get both "New York, Time Square" and "New York, Statue of Liberty" as the list. How do I do that?
N/B: each field may contain lots of words.


I tried the above code, but the error says I can use arrayContains ONLY ONCE.

That's the expected behavior. If you use more than one array-contains call in the same query, such an error will be thrown.
If your app's use-case requires filtering on fromController.text and toController.text keywords at the same time, there is a workaround that can help you solve this constraint.
Since you cannot use array-contains, then you have to make a little change in your Firestore document schema. So you should consider creating a new field for each individual value and then chain multiple where() calls. Calling this function multiple times in the same query will work perfectly fine:
Your document schema should look like this:
departureCity: { 
    "keyword1": true,
    "keyword2": true,
    "keyword3": true
}

arrivalCity: { 
    "keyword4": true,
    "keyword5": true,
    "keyword6": true
}

As you can see, the DepartureCity and the ArrivalCity fields are not arrays anymore, but Maps (objects). So using such a schema, you'll be able to find all the documents that match keyword1 and keyword4 at the same time. The query that is needed looks something like this:
db.collection('collectionPath')
    .where("departureCity.keyword1", "==", true)
    .where("arrivalCity.keyword4", "==", true);

Where keyword1 represents the value of fromController.text and keyword4 represents the value of toController.text.
You can also add an order by the desired property call but don't forget to create an index, as explained in my answer from the following post:

Firestore whereEqualTo, orderBy and limit(1) not working


Thank you for the reply. But I'm a bit lost and I would be glad if you could help me out. What do the "keywords" represent?. Could you please take a look at the edited question

What you are looking for is called a search, and unfortunately, Firebase doesn't provide full-text search. Perhaps this answer might help.

Did my answer/comment help? Can I help you with other information?
